# How to place my Application Account with Android native accounts

Tags: android

Hi I am fairly new to android development. I am writing this because I do not know what to search for. I basically have an application where you create an account to gain access to it and use it. I would like my account to be a part of the Accounts listed in the Android system like the image below:

[image: Screen Shot from Android 4.1.2 System Settings]

Please show me the way or help me with what should I be looking for. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [link](http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is how to implement your account type. It needs to interact with the AccountManager class in order to be handled by the system (and appear in the account list displayed in your screenshot).
This lesson : http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html covers the basics of this.
This blog entry : http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/ should cover all the specifities of this task that you need to know.